# What part of the transaction is scriptSig in?

Tags: script

I was reading this paper 
https://web.archive.org/web/20140331191527/http://bitcoinhistory.net/Technical_Papers/ProgrammingBitcoinTransactionScripts.pdf
and I have the following question:

ScriptPubKey accompanies a transaction output and specifies under which conditions it can be claimed. ScriptSig accompanies a transaction input and is used to prove that the referenced output can be rightfully claimed.

So in page 2 the ScriptSig should be in Input TX and ScriptPubKey should be in output TX? Author says that scriptA is ScriptSig.

Comment: the link you posted is dead, at least for me

Comment: [Here's a mirror.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140331191527/http://bitcoinhistory.net/Technical_Papers/ProgrammingBitcoinTransactionScripts.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by that too. Here's the picture with some more labels on it.

[image: labeled better]